# Unable to override snakeyaml library version in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, snakeyaml

Folks, I have been using spring boot parent version 2.7.5, which is exposing snakeyaml jar version 1.30 and I wish to override snakeyaml version to 1.33 as sonarent is complaining certain vulnerabilities with 1.30 version during container-security-scan in gitlab pipeline. I already tried below stuff to override snakeyaml version-

1. Used snakeyaml version as properties inside  tag in pom.xml
2. Added individual dependency for snakeyaml with updated version.
3. Added dependency under dependency-management tag.

Still the container-security-scan complaints for the vulnerability present in version 1.30 as it is not able to override it. Although generating effective pom of my local machine shows that version 1.33 of snakeyaml is getting used.

Comment: Have you seen this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/32221 ? Might help ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Thanks for the answer but it differs from my issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [upgrade to SnakeYaml 1.31 in spring-boot-starter-parent 2.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73707768/upgrade-to-snakeyaml-1-31-in-spring-boot-starter-parent-2-7-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve this now. The issue was with opentelemetry exposing snakeyaml older version (but somehow not sure why it was not showing it in dependency tree or in effective pom.xml) and when I upgraded the open telemetry version along with properties tag for snakeyaml version upgraded, it worked for me. Now I don't see any container-security-scan issue anymore.

docker-scan helped me by giving the hint open telemetry is the culprit.