AsyncRequestNotUsableException: Response not usable after response errors
In a recent attempt to upgrade to spring-boot:3.2.4 from 3.2.0, we are ending up facing an error thrown for few requests(no particular mapping) to our servers. I could not infer much from the stacktrace of these errors either. These are logged via the @ControllerAdvice with the very first line of code as:
logger.error("Something went wrong while making a request to places!", throwable);

The immediate stack trace is as follows:
Something went wrong while making a request to places!
org.springframework.web.context.request.async.AsyncRequestNotUsableException: ServletOutputStream failed to write: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest$LifecycleHttpServletResponse.handleIOException(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:320) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest$LifecycleServletOutputStream.write(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:378) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingOutputStream.write(StreamUtils.java:264) ~[spring-core-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:2203) ~[jackson-core-2.15.4.jar!/:2.15.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.writeString(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:521) ~[jackson-core-2.15.4.jar!/:2.15.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StringSerializer.serialize(StringSerializer.java:41) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar!/:2.15.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFieldsUsing(MapSerializer.java:905) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar!/:2.15.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeWithoutTypeInfo(MapSerializer.java:762) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar!/:2.15.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:720) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar!/:2.15.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:35) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar!/:2.15.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar!/:2.15.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:772) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar!/:2.15.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar!/:2.15.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:119) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar!/:2.15.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:79) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar!/:2.15.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serialize(IndexedListSerializer.java:18) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar!/:2.15.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar!/:2.15.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:772) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar!/:2.15.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar!/:2.15.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar!/:2.15.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar!/:2.15.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar!/:2.15.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:479) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar!/:2.15.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:399) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar!/:2.15.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1568) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar!/:2.15.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1061) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar!/:2.15.4]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:483) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:114) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:297) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:190) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:830) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]

followed up with the cause as:
Suppressed: org.springframework.web.context.request.async.AsyncRequestNotUsableException: Response not usable after response errors.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest$LifecycleHttpServletResponse.obtainLockAndCheckState(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:314) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest$LifecycleServletOutputStream.write(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:373) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingOutputStream.write(StreamUtils.java:264) ~[spring-core-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:2203) ~[jackson-core-2.15.4.jar!/:2.15.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.close(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1227) ~[jackson-core-2.15.4.jar!/:2.15.4]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:452) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:114) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:297) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:190) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:830) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
...
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:773) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:676) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:379) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest$LifecycleServletOutputStream.write(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:375) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar!/:6.1.5]
    ... 82 more

Not able to relate much to any change from the release note for 3.2.4 either. Restoring the version to 3.2.0 resolves the issue for now.
What I am curious to understand first is what is the actual cause of the issue?
Then follow it up with a possible fix with updated versions itself.

Update: As asked, sharing the primary dependencies of the application:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <!--https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74781733/vulnerable-dependency-mavenorg-yamlsnakeyaml-->
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
    <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!--logging and validators-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>

Update 2: Upgraded to spring-boot:3.2.5, but the error persists with the latest release too.

Have you tried 3.2.5? There have been some changes with regards to headers (although I believe that was only client related not server). Can you post your dependencies, make sure you don't have conflicting dependencies as well.

Hi @M.Deinum. I haven't tried 3.2.5 yet. Updated with primary dependencies in use. Analysing the dependency tree and comparing it, didn't result in any conflicting transitive resolution. Is there any specific change(reference) that you can redirect me to for the change mentioned?

Would be helpful, if users can post what debugging details are required to make the question meaningful.

@M.Deinum tried 3.2.5, but the error persists with the latest release too.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/32509

@agassner Thank you for sharing this. It seems relevant but there is no conclusive takeaway from the thread. Shall I infer that this would be the implementation as we advance and handle this exception at the advice?

Do you resolve your issue? I encountered a similar with 3.2.6 and I can't see working solution

@newOne To summarise - Not really! Details - Followed links through the one shared by agassner and found that mostly this is a framework layer change and intended to decorate an underlying IOException. At our application layer, we were not really handling it earlier and we decided that we are good to live with an older version for now.

Okay, thx for information :)

It happened as well in Spring Boot 3 ; Jetty 12 stackoverflow.com/questions/685271/…, and others. With only small files <10Kb, and many requests. Probably related to timeout.

In 3.3 I have this one org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver  - Resolved [org.springframework.web.context.request.async.AsyncRequestNotUsableException: ServletOutputStream failed to write: reset] when quickly close a browser in the middle of it.

As you experience this exception for a few requests only this could be caused by a timeout. Probably the default setting has been changed. Try switching the request timeout off. If it helps then you can adjust it to a reasonable value.
spring.mvc.async.request-timeout=-1


Thank you for the answer, is the default for this configuration modified with the version upgrade or underlying dependency updates? Asking, since updating a config to have unlimited timeout on a production setup directly might not be a good idea for us.

Unlimited just to check if this is the cause. Afterwards you should adjust it to a reasonable value.

I have verified that this is not resolving the issue mentioned either.
