# Maven: How to update transitive dependency (snakeyaml)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I scanned my Spring Boot app using Synk and there are some vulnerabilities after scan. For this reason, I needed to update `snakeyaml`, but as far as I know, it is a dependency below spring-boot-starter-web.

Here is the dependency tree for my project:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.17.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.30:compile
```

In this scene, how can I update snakeyaml? Should I add a remove annotation below the spring-boot-starter-web and then add the following dependency in pom.xml?

I know the last version also has a vulnerability, but I just wanted to know what should I do for this kind of situations (assume that the last version has no vulnerability)? Any idea?

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.yaml/snakeyaml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
    <version>1.33</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Upgrade to Spring BOot 2.7.8 (which includes newer versions and is compatible with your current version of Spring Boot). Else add `<snakeyaml.version>1.33</snakeyaml.version>` to the `<properties>` section of the pom. But the best would be to upgrade to the latest Spring BOot version in the 2.7 line.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, but but what if I don't update spring-boot-starter-web and just want to update snakeyaml ? Could you please a steps for that?

Comment: Why do people alsways stop reading after the first sentence?! I already stated what to do to only upgrade snakeyaml -> **Else add <snakeyaml.version>1.33</snakeyaml.version> to the <properties> section of the pom** it is literay there, but as stated you should really upgrade. Sticking with the same major 2.7 is generally not an issue with upgrading minor versions like to 2.7.8 which include the proper dependencies and other CVE fixes as well.

Comment: @M.Deinum Before asking the question I tried to update to 3.0.0, but there are many breaks in the project. Then I tried your suggestion, but still vulnerability error as "**Introduced through:** org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web@3.0.0 > org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter@2.7.8 > org.yaml:snakeyaml@1.30" ---- **Fix:** Upgrade to org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web@3.0.0". >>>

Comment: @M.Deinum >>>  So, instead of sharing your suggestion on comments, could you please post them as an answer? Because I have no previous experience and want to know 2 things: **1** Fix the problem with the most proper way. **2.** How should I resolve this when there is a transitive dependency (I think I may need to remove snakeyml first and then add it).

Comment: The most proper way is to upgrade Spring Boot. Again as stated if it is a transitive dependency use the version tag I stated in the properties section. This will override the version that Spring Boot is pulling in. YOu don't need to do anything more (this is even explained in the regular Spring Boot documentation).

Comment: Also yuou didn't do as I suggested as you updated **part of spring boot** which I suggested **not** to do.

Comment: Updating Spring Boot version to 2.7.8 did not fix the problem as I already stated before. But when I add `<snakeyaml.version>1.33</snakeyaml.version>` to the `<properties>` section, it seems ok. I am just wondering, when there is a transitive dependency, should we just add the related dependency to the `<properties>` section? Or do we also need to exclude this dependency from the parent dependency (e.g. `spring-boot-starter-web`). You did not clarified about this issue. Any idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I did in the answer I gave... Which explains everything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [upgrade to SnakeYaml 1.31 in spring-boot-starter-parent 2.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73707768/upgrade-to-snakeyaml-1-31-in-spring-boot-starter-parent-2-7-3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off all don't panic and step back. Although the dependency mentioned has a vulnerability, if you don't actually use it (i.e. no YAML in your application) it actually doesn't apply. Those dependency scans are pretty dumb as they can only see dependencies not the fact that you are or aren't using them.

That being said, to fix you should upgrade the Spring Boot version for your application. For this, assuming you are using a Spring Boot as a parent, update that version.

```xml
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.8</version>
</parent>
```

**NOTE:** Don't mix modules of different versions of Spring Boot (or any framework/library for that matter) as that will lead to problems. So don't put a `version` tag in your dependencies (at least not the `spring-boot-starter-*` ones!).

This has Snake YAML 1.30, if you can you could also upgrade to 3.0.2 which actually includes the 1.33 version.

To upgrade only Snake YAML you can just override the version property used by Spring Boot to manage the dependencies. The version properties are documented in the [Spring Boot Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/dependency-versions.html#appendix.dependency-versions.properties). How to override those versions is documented in the [Spring Boot Plugin Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.2/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#using.parent-pom).

In short you would need to override the `snakeyaml.version` property with the version you wish to use (that is only for 2.7.x) if you upgrade to 3.02 you don't need this.

```xml
<properties>
 <snakeyaml.version>1.33</snakeyaml.version>
</properties>
```

This will pull in that version. You don't need to exclude anything or use dependency management for this. Drawback when a new version of Snake YAML comes out and Spring Boot pulls that in, this will override it. So take care when updating after this.

This all being said, as mentioned in the beginning the fact that a certain jar/dependency is included doesn't mean it is a risk. If not used it won't pose a risk, so instead of panicking on Snyk warnings you should properly investigate them.

Comment: Very good, clean and important explanations; much more useful than documentation and please be sure that I took note all of your explanations and will considerate. Thank you so much! Regarding to some points you mentioned, could you please add some comment for these? >>>

Comment: **1.** Sometimes, I also think about the proper usage of the `version` property in `pom.xml`. Then, do you mean that except from some basic fields e.g. `<java.version>`, I should not use it, right?

Comment: **2.** But, there are some dependencies that uses the same version with the related Spring Boot libraries e.g. `spring-boot-starter-validation`, `springfox-boot-starter`. In this scene, should I change all of the version at the same time when I need to change one of them? I mean, what would you suggest for using version on pom.xml? For example, sometimes I need to specify the version and may need to use lower version for compatibility. As far as I know, when we don't use version, it uses the last version for that dependency.

Comment: 1. You should avoid it as much as possible at least to manage/override Spring Boot dependencies. 2. Your knowledge is wrong, it uses the dependency as specified, which can be controled by the dependency management block from Spring BOot. It doesn't use the latest version by default.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to update whatever brings you the dependency (here: spring-boot-starter-web)
2. If not possible: Add an entry to `<dependencyManagement>` with the newer version and put a comment into the `pom.xml` why you do this (Vulnerability XY).

Comment: UPdating a single part of Spring Boot is a bad idea as it will lead (eventually) to incompatible versions. To use a specific version of a dependency Spring Boot has documented ways of doing so.

Comment: If it's intended for a particular dependency as in such case it make sense and is neccessary....... using dependencyManagement works fine... in such case the best thing would be to upgrade spring boot itself ... but that's not always possible...

Comment: Thanks for your replies, but but **what if I don't update spring-boot-starter-web and just want to update snakeyaml** ? Could you please a steps for that?

Comment: @batman This is my second advice. Put snakeyaml into `<dependencyManagement>`. Alternatively, you can probably override a property that defines the version in the spring boot parent POM.

Comment: @JFabianMeier Could you please post it as an example? Because I have no idea how to do it properly? Any example for pom.xml with the related lines?